# How to apply comment style to text pieces which may have overlapped parts?

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

Say I have a contenteditable div with text contents. Now I want to add comments (which are outside the container div) to some pieces of the text. And when the user clicks the comment, the corresponding text pieces should be styled (e.g. red color). The difficulty is that these pieces may have overlapped parts (like `ab` and `bc` in `abc`).

And I want the style applied based on the very characters starting and ending a sequence. So if new contents (even if the same pieces) are added before the starting character or after the ending character, the style will not be applied.

To split each overlapped part into a new element may help but seems not that clean (especially when the contents contain many nested tags). Are there some better ways?

Comment: where is your source code? what error you are facing

Comment: @Nishant Well, I'm not facing an error, just trying to figure out a possible mechanism.  The question has been revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags must be nested, so you should use something like splitting.js. Two problems are, with content-editable they could drag-drop anything (so id's may be lost), and the eventListener could fire multiple times (so be careful with regex). I doubt that your intent to intercept content-editable is generally enforceable. As you juggle multiple, complex, nonstandard scenarios, how does the user benefit?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The question is revised now.